# OpenGL GlOrtho no primitives appearing

Tags: java, netbeans, opengl-1.x

I am drawing on a texture and then rendering this texture to the screen using GL_QUADS. There is no problem drawing the texture on screen, but while drawing to the texture the only operation that has any effect is glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); - this sets the whole texture to the colour I want. It is however impossible to draw any primitives.

The following code should absolutely cover the whole texture with black, right?

```
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, texRenderer.framebufferID);                        // switch to the texture framebuffer

glClearColor(1.0f,0.5f,0.0f,1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, texRenderer.pixelsWidth, 0, texRenderer.pixelsHeight, 1, -1);

// switch to modelview matrix before rendering objects
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glColor4f(0,0,0,1);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2f(-100, -100);
glVertex2f(-100, 100);
glVertex2f(100, 100);
glVertex2f(100, -100);
glEnd();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

//RenderScene(sim, stateMachine, viewSettings, commandMgr, font, texRenderer.pixelsWidth, texRenderer.pixelsHeight, isMainView, drawText);

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);                        // switch back to normal framebuffer
```

Instead it is orange.

pixelsWidth and pixelsHeight are both equal to 64. I've made sure the viewport is set up correctly. Also glGetError() returns 0.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Took me 6 hours but the problem is solved. I was wrong. The viewport was not properly set. Before rendering to a texture, be sure to add the following line:

```
glViewport(0, 0, textureWidth, textureHeight);
```

And also unbind any currently bound textures using

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```